# How to optimize a player for React

Tags: react-native

i am trying to load an streamplayer in a react app.
It does work the way below but it needs to be fixed, as i don't want document.getElementById in the react code.
But i am strugeling to get this resoved.

I got the followng code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { FaPlayCircle, FaPauseCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import { GetConfiguration } from "../../../api";
import { Base, Text, Column, Flex, Button, LayoutGridItem } from "../../../common";

  export const RadioView = () => {
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio( GetConfiguration<string>("radio.stream.url") ));
  const [isPlaying] = useState(false);
  
    const startRadio = () => {
      var resp = audio.play();

      if (resp !== undefined) {
        resp
            .then((_) => {
              document.getElementById("startRadio").style.color = "blue";
              document.getElementById("pauseRadio").style.color = "black";
            })
        }
    };
        
    const pauseRadio = () => {
    document.getElementById("startRadio").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("pauseRadio").style.color = "red";
    audio.pause();
  };

  const updateVolume = (volume) => {
    let radioVolume = Math.round(volume);

    radioVolume = Math.max(0, radioVolume);
    radioVolume = Math.min(100, radioVolume);

    audio.volume = radioVolume / 100;
  }

  audio.autoplay = true;
  audio.volume = 0.3;
  
  return (
    <Base className="notification-radio rounded">
          <Column>
            <Flex gap={1}>
            <Button
                id="startRadio"
                type="button"
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#F1B941", color: "blue", cursor: "pointer", }}
                onClick={(e) => startRadio()}
              >
                {" "}<FaPlayCircle className="radio-font-icons fa-icon" />{" "}
              </Button>
              <Button
                id="pauseRadio"
                type="button"
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#F1B941", color: "black", cursor: "pointer", }}
                onClick={(e) => pauseRadio()}
              >
                {" "}<FaPauseCircle className="radio-font-icons fa-icon" />{" "}
            </Button>
        </Flex>
              <input
                onChange={(e) => updateVolume(e.target.value)}
                style={{ marginTop: "7px", display: "inline-block" }}
                type="range"
                className="form-range"
                id="customRange1"
                min="0"
                max="100"
                step="1"
              >
              </input>
            <div className="col-md-1" />
      </Column>
    </Base>
  );
};
```

How do i fix the document.getElementById.

I think the button should be something like:

```
<Button  
    onClick={() => audio.play()}
    type="button"
    style={{ backgroundColor: "#F1B941", color: audio.paused ? "black" : "blue", cursor: "pointer",    }}
>
```

But how should i solve the:

- const pauseRadio
- if (resp !== undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :)

````
import { useState } from "react";
import { FaPlayCircle, FaPauseCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import { GetConfiguration } from "../../../api";
import { Base, Text, Column, Flex, Button, LayoutGridItem } from "../../../common";

  export const RadioView = () => {
  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(new Audio( GetConfiguration<string>("radio.stream.url") ));
  
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState({
     playing: true,
     pause: false
   });
  
  const PlayClick = () => {
      var resp = audio.play();

      if (resp !== undefined) {
        resp
        setPlayer({ ...player, playing: true, pause: false });
        }
    }
  
    const PauseClick = () => {
    setPlayer({ ...player, playing: false, pause: true });
    audio.pause();
  };```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).